# modalpopupextendar overlapped by youtube embed iframe

Tags: c#, gridview, iframe, youtube, embed

I have a gridview that is dynamically filling by youtube iframe embed objects. Everything is going well be when i am opening a modalpopup on the page, its getting overlapped by youtube iframe.

Please check the image -

[image: modalpopupextendar overlapped by youtube embed iframe]

Here is the embed code-

```
<iframe style="z-index:0;" width="300" height="200" src='http://<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"URL") %>'> frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="false"> </iframe>
```

can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this at the end of the youtube link: `?wmode=Opaque`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do anything about that unless you will hide the Youtube iframe. The Youtude control is a flash ActiveX object and the ActiveX objects have the topmost z-order, which you cannot overlap.

Comment: seems wired, few day back i found similar issue with a javascript horizontal menu that was overlapped by a flash object. I was able to fix that, but here i cont found any `<object>` tag sothat i can process.

Ok I'm trying to show this modalpopup to any other place on the page.

Answer (score 0):

seems wired,
few day back i found similar issue with a javascript horizontal menu that was overlapped by a flash object. I was able to fix that, but here i cont found any `<object>` tag sothat i can process.

Ok I'm trying to show this modalpopup to any other place on the page.